# awk command to modify a column in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have written a bash script (File.sh) to change the third column of a file (File.txt) with a particular string (NULL).

**File.txt** -

```
abc def 123
qwe gfh 456
```

**File.sh** -

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1='file.txt'
while IFS= read -r line
do
    awk '$3= "NULL"' file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
done <"$FILE1"
```

and this works fine.

**output**

```
abc def NULL
qwe gfh NULL
```

But now I'am trying to update the third column using a variable instead of a text-

```
var='NULL'
awk '$3= $var' file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

this doesn't work. what can be the mistake in syntax.

Comment: You have taken an O(n) operation and made it O(n^2).  For each line in the file, you are going through the entire file and changing the entry in the 3rd column.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
var="NULL"
awk -v var="$var" '{$3=var} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_fle
```

Comment: It worked. thanks.